# Integral test and the gamma function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, gamma-function

Suppose you are given a series with a factorial, is it appropriate to replace $n!$ with $\Gamma(n+1)$ and apply the integral test? It seems like even if there are other methods that work to show convergence better, this still might be potentially a good technique for approximating a series that doesn't fit into the category of trivial to evaluate.

Comment: How would you provide for (1) when you were dividing by $n!$ and (2) the fact that you would have to integrate it even after making the substitution. Do you know a simple anti-derivative for $\Gamma(x)$ or--if not--how to work around this in the integral test?

Comment: The basic integral test that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(k)$ and $\int_1^\infty f(x) \, dx$ converge/diverge together applies when $f$ is nonnegative and decreasing for $x  \geqslant 1$.  As long as this holds the appearance of the gamma function might not be a problem since it coincides with factorial at integers and is eventually monotone.  You don't need to compute the integral -- only prove convergence.  That may or may not be feasible depending on the situation.

Comment: I DO want to estimate the series though so I believe I'd need to evaluate the integral.

Comment: Also..... Can I apply L'hospital as well to the gamma function when dealing with the factorial?

Comment: I'm trying to evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n!}{n^n}$. I find the ratio test inconclusive ( unless I made an error) and using the root test (and wolfram) i have $\frac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n}\to e^{-1}$ but I don't know how to show this last fact and so I thought I could solve the original problem with the integral test and get a great estimate on the series too

Comment: $e^{-1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} (n!)^n /n = \lim_{x \to \infty} \Gamma(x+1))^{1/x} /x $ is true. Using LHR requires evaluating $\frac{d}{dx} \exp ( \log \Gamma (x+1) / x) = \Gamma(x+1)^{1/x} ( - \log \Gamma (x+1) /x^2 + \frac{d}{dx} \log \Gamma (x+1) /x)$ and finding the asymptotic behavior as $x \to \infty$.  The root test shows the series converges since $e^{-1} < 1$.

Comment: The ratio test also works since $\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}} \frac{n^n}{n!} = 1/(1 + 1/n)^n \to e^{-1}$.

Comment: Embarrassingly easy to see now. Thank you